# Any custom ROM reboots Kindle Fire

Tags: custom-roms, amazon-kindle-fire

I've installed FireFireFire and TWRP on my Kindle Fire. That went ok and I can boot into TWRP. Then I tried installing many custom ROMs (SimpleCM9, jandycane, MIUI, AlienDroidV4.0.zip) but all with the some result - flash ok, reboot, boot logo/animation of custom ROM, then reboot and Kindle hangs on next boot.

TWRP 2.2.2.1

Comment: did you make sure to completely wipe the dalvik cache and factory reset the device between each ROM flash?

Comment: Yes. I'm was reset cache/dalvik cache/Factory and separately all this and system.